# Исправление опечатки на PHP+regex

Tags: регулярные-выражения, php

```
$a='я пошел гулять на улицу АЗина';
```

Надо в этой строке исправить ошибку АЗина на Азина на PHP одной строчкой регулярным выражением. Если есть красивые решения без регулярок, то вообщем тоже океюшки.

Comment: оффтоп:

>регуляркным выражением

Дааа, тут регуляркой уже не справиться...

Answer (score 2):

Рабочий в utf8:

```
$a=iconv('utf-8', 'windows-1251', 'я пошел гулять на улицу АЗина');

$b=$a{0};
for($i=1;$i<strlen($a);$i++) $b .= preg_match('/[A-ZА-Я]{2}/',$a{$i-1}.$a{$i})?strtolower($a{$i}):$a{$i};

echo iconv('windows-1251', 'utf-8', $b);
```

Если документ в cp1251,

```
$a='я пошел гулять на улицу АЗина';
for($i=0;$i<strlen($a);$i++)$b.=($i==0?$a{0}:(preg_match('/[A-ZА-Я]{2}/',$a{$i-1}.$a{$i})?strtolower($a{$i}):$a{$i}));
echo $b;
```

Преобразование - одна строка)

Comment: думаю прощще будет mb_ и /u использовать для UTF, но все равно спасибо.

Comment: Ну да, с `mb_func_overload=On` в любой кодировке будет вариант 2.

Answer (score 2):

ИМХО:

Автозамена такой опечатки - не есть гуд, ибо! - как вы собираетесь отслеживать аббревиатуры??

Посему предлагаю как-то так ( JS ):

```
submit = function (){
    if (
      str.test( /[А-ЯA-Z]{2}/ ) &&
      confirm( 'Возможно опечатка в строке Х [OK - исправлю, Отмена - не опечатка]' )
    ) return;

    //отправка
}
```

UPD:

Можно так:

```
<?
  $str_in = 'Я пошел гулять на улицу АЗина';

  $str_out =  preg_replace_callback(
    '/([А-Я])([А-Я])/',
    create_function('$match', 'return $match[ 1 ].strtolower( $match[ 2 ] );'),
    $str_in
  );

  echo $str_out;
?>
```

Единственное - проблема с кодировками... Как побороть - не подскажу)

Comment: с обнаружением проблем нет: [A-ЯA-Z][A-ЯA-Z][а-яa-z]

Comment: Есть много названий вида 'ИЭиУ' и т.п., поэтому проблемы есть)

Comment: `Згтещ Switcher` же набил такую базу, и тс не обломается, если сильно надо будет) На крайняк проверять первую и последнюю букву, если обе upcase, то аббревиатура. Заодно всякие СИ, AI, MS и т.п. трогать не будет.

Answer (score 1):

Вообщем есть здесь решение без регулярок - читать **ascii-код** каждого символа,
затем сравнивать предыдущий с только что прочитанным, если только что прочитанный символ имеет код больше предыдущего или равен ему, то прибавлять 64 к коду. По моему так...

Это вкратце...
Если данное решение заинтересовало, расскажу о подробностях =)

Comment: Спасибо, это тяжкий труд в многа строк, хочу однострочник

Comment: В одну строчку не получится =)

Answer (score 1):

Вот что первое пришло на ум:

```
$a='я пошел гулять на улицу АЗина';
$words = explode(" ", $a);
for($i=0; $i<count($words); $i++){
   if(preg_match("/[А-ЯA-Z]/", $words[$i][0])){
       $words[$i] = ucfirst(strtolower($words[$i]));
   }
}
$a = implode(" ", $words);
```

Одной строчкой никак))

Будет проблема, если в предложении встречаются запятые или точки.